# Why does this Albacore zip task not create the zip file?

Tags: ruby, rake, albacore

When I run the zip task with `rake –-trace`, it shows the calls to `default` and `zip_up_files`, but it doesn't create the zip file. It doesn't give me an error message. What am I doing wrong?

```
require 'albacore'

task :default => :zip_up_files

zip :zip_up_files do |zip|
  zip.directories_to_zip 'C:\\Temp\\StuffToZip'
  zip.output_file = 'out.zip'
  zip.output_path = 'C:\\Temp'
end
```

Comment: Hey, Paul, I got your answer right down there! Come on and vote/accept/comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your rakefile on my machine and got no errors and no zip file! I looked into the Albacore [zip task](https://github.com/Albacore/albacore/blob/dev/lib/albacore/zipdirectory.rb#L28) and it uses the Ruby [ZipFile](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/classes/Zip/ZipFile.html) class. That seems to be a pure Ruby implementation of the zip archive. So, next thing I tried was fixing up the paths to use *forward slashes*. That worked!

```
zip :zip_up_files do |zip|
  zip.directories_to_zip 'C:/Temp/StuffToZip'
  zip.output_file = 'out.zip'
  zip.output_path = 'C:/Temp'
end
```

I had another thought, that maybe you didn't have permissions to write on the C drive. I wasn't able to reproduce that, but it's my recommendation to maybe be in a User controlled directory. Even if it's an automated build user. Just double check.